# Completeness of a normed vector space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

This is captured from a chapter talking about completeness of metric space in Real Analysis, Carothers, 1ed. 
[image]

I have been confused by two questions:

1. What does absolutely summable mean in metric space? Does it mean the norm of xi(i=1,2,3,...) that belongs to norm vector space X is summable?
2. 2nd part of the proof should try to show that if ∑xn(n from 1 to infinity) converges in X whenever ||xn||(n from 1 to infinity) is summable, then X is complete. However, why does the author prove the subsequence of {xn} converges?

Thanks^_^

Comment: Absolutely summable means the terms $\|x_k\|$ are summable.

Comment: If any subsequence of a Cauchy sequence converges, then the whole sequence converges (to the same point, of course).

Comment: @copper.hat: if any subsequence of a Cauchy sequence converges, then we need to prove ||xn(k+1) - xnk|| < ε for any ε. However, there is only 2^(-k) that has been taken into account which is a particular value instead of any ε.

Comment: @copper.hat: ur first comment does make sense, thank u^_^

Comment: You are **given** that $x_n$ is Cauchy, and you need to show it converges to some point. If you can show that $x_{n_k} \to x$ for some $x$, then you are finished. (You have $\|x_n-x\| \le \|x_n-x_{n_k}\| + \|x_{n_k}-x\|$, from which you can show the whole sequence converges.)

Comment: @copper.hat: oh, according to inequation ∥xn−x∥≤∥xn−xnk∥+∥xnk−x∥,since xn is Cauchy, we will get xn approaching xnk when k goes to infinity. Then, since xnk converges to x as k goes to infinity, we get xn approaches x, which means cauchy sequence {xn} converges to x belonging to X---completeness X, is that right?

Comment: Well, because $x_n$ is Cauchy, the $x_n-x_{n-k}$ term can be made as small as you want ($>0$), and because it converges on a subsequence, $x-x_{n-k}$ can be made as small as you want ($>0$), hence the entire sequence converges to $x$.

Comment: @copper.hat: haha, thanks a lot. Make sense^_^

Comment: Glad to help! ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fundamental distinction between the two series. Let $(x_i)$ be a sequence in $X$.

Then $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{\|x_i\|}$ is a series in $\mathbb{R}$. If   $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{\|x_i\|}$ is convergent, then the series $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{x_i}$ is said to be absolutely summable.

On the other hand, $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{x_i}$ is said to be summable if it is convergent in the normed vector space. (i.e. $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{x_i}=x\in X$).

---

Now we address your second question.

A standard theorem is that if a Cauchy sequence has a convergent subsequence then it is itself convergent and converges to the same limit as the subsequence.

Proof:

Take $(x_i)$ a Cauchy sequence. Let ($x_{i_k}$) be a convergent subsequence with limit $x$. Fix $\epsilon > 0$. For $N$ large enough, if $i_k,i>N$

$$\|x_i-x_{i_k}\|<\frac{\epsilon}{2} \textbf{ and } ||x_{i_k}-x||<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

The first inequality is due to the Cauchyness of the sequence. The second by the convergence of the subsequence.

By the triangle inequality, $\|x_i-x\|<\epsilon$ for $i>N$. Hence $(x_i)$ converges to $x$.

---

**Comment on book proof:**  As a consequence of this theorem, the author just needs to show that any Cauchy sequence in $X$ has a convergent subsequence in order to prove that it is convergent hence showing that $X$ is complete.

Comment: thank u!BTW, which book will contain "A standard theorem is that if a Cauchy sequence has a convergent subsequence then it is itself convergent and converges to the same limit as the subsequence" in metric space or norm space? Can u introduce some of them? im really interested in and if it contains some answers or solutions to questions following every chapter of the book,  that will be preferred.^_^

Comment: Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis".

Comment: I just referred to my copy of baby Rudin. It is exercise #20 in Chapter 3. You would benefit greatly from reading that Chapter.

Comment: awesome, got it. thanks a lot^_^

Answer (score 0):

1. $X$ is a normed space (not just a metric space). So a sequence $\{x_n\}$ is absolutely summable when $\sum\|x_n\| < \infty$.
2. A common theorem in this game is that if $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, then given any subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ converges then so does $\{x_n\}$. Moreover, if $x_{n_k} \to L$ then $x_n \to L$. As an idea of the proof of this:
   $$
   \|x_n - L\| \leq \|x_n - x_{n_k}\| + \|x_{n_k} - L\|
   $$
   You can control the size of $\|x_n - x_{n_k}\|$  by the Cauchy assumption, and the $\|x_{n_k}-L\|$ term by the assumption of convergence.

Comment: for 1, does make sense; for 2, im still confusing that if any subsequence of a Cauchy sequence converges, then we need to prove ||xn(k+1) - xnk|| < ε for any ε. However, there is only 2^(-k) that has been taken into account which is a particular value instead of any ε.

Comment: By assumption $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy. So, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $n_{\epsilon}$ such that if $n, m \geq n_{\epsilon}$ then $\|x_n-x_m\|< \epsilon$. This is true for *any* $\epsilon$. So, what the author does is develop a subsequence by taking $\epsilon=2^{-k}$ for $k = 1, 2, ... $ and finding appropriate values in $\{x_n\}$.